# Routing loopback using OSPF

Tags: cisco, routing, ospf, loopback

[image]

Here is a simple network using OSPF. Router2 has got LoopBack0 with IP address **10.0.2.1 255.255.255.0**. I add this network to OSPF:

**Router(config-router)#net 10.0.2.0 0.0.0.255 area 0**

When I dispaly routing table in Router2 - I see there **10.0.2.0/24** directly connected. But in Router3 routing table I see

**10.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets**

**O       10.0.2.1 [110/65] via 10.0.0.2, 00:00:12, Serial0/0/0**

Why there is prefix /32  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loopback interfaces are considered as host routes, so they are always advertised with a /32 mask.

If you want to advertise the whole subnet, you have to change the network type to **point to point** like this:

```
Interface loopback 0
 ip ospf network point-to-point
```

then OSPF will advertise the subnet with the configured mask.

Comment: Thank you for posting. Worked for me! Thanks